# Ubuntu vm under proxy: browser is not able to resolve dns

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, firefox, http-proxy

I don't quite figure out why I'm not able to get dns lookpu resolution into my browser (firefox) inside my ubuntu virtual machine.

`apt-get`, `git`, `maven`, `gradle` and other tools are configured in order to use proxy settings and they are able to resolve and download packages and dependencies straightforwardly.

I'm so exhausted to try to survey what's wrong.

I've tried to set:
 1. specific browser proxy settings
 2. use OS environment settings (HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY)

Neither of ones have solved my problem. My browser is not able to resolve names.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you check, in `about:config`, values of `network.dns.disablePrefetch` and `network.dns.forceResolve`? There is any config value in `network.dns.*` which value is not the default one? (check column `status`)

Comment: `network.dns.disablePrefetch` -> `default`
`network.dns.forceResolve` -> `default`
`network.dns.*` -> all are `default`

Comment: Place those values to disable/off and try using Firefox.

Comment: I doesn't work.

Comment: It's strange. Check also `network.dnsCache` and `network.proxy` parameters. Is `network.proxy.no_proxies_on` parameter correct?

Comment: Wild guess. How did you installed firefox? Using ubuntu package manager? Can you try to download a fresh copy from the site? Try the [developer edition](https://www.mozilla.org/it/firefox/channel/desktop/).